# Border with multirow and multicolumn

Tags: tables, multirow, multicolumn, border

Following example:

```
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{tabular}{cc|c|c|c|c|c|}
\cline{3-7}
& & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{something} \\ \cline{3-7}
& & AAA & BBB & CCC & DDD & EEE\\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{sth}} } 
& line 1 & x & x & x & x & x \\ \cline{2-7}
& line 2 & x & x & x & x & x \\ \cline{2-7}
\end{tabular}
```

1. Why is the border on the left side missing?

[image]

2. Why can I not make the columns fixed width (like `c{4cm})`? this gives me an error message ' Illegal pream-token (2.0cm): `c' used.' but I am pretty sure it has worked for me like this...

Comment: Does each column have to be 4cm wide?

Comment: The 5 right columns should be equally wide to fill the page width.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a solution. I took the opportunity to improve the vertical padding of cells, and defined a `\nocell` command to have a number of empty cells; its argument is the number of consecutive empty cells.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array, makecell, rotating}
\setcellgapes{2pt}
\newcommand\nocell[1]{\multicolumn{#1}{c|}{}}

\begin{document}

\makegapedcells
\begin{tabular}{|c*{6}{|p{2cm}}|}
  \cline{3-7}
  \nocell{2}& \multicolumn{5}{c|}{something} \\ \cline{3-7}
  \nocell{2} & AAA & BBB & CCC & DDD & EEE\\ \hline
  \multirowcell{2}[0.5ex]{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{sth}} & line 1 & x & x & x & x & x \\ \cline{2-7}
 & line 2 & x & x & x & x & x \\ \cline{1-7}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, especially the new command is useful. However, do you maybe also have an idea what is wrong with my example, since it really puzzles me?

Comment: Yes: it seems to be the `\multicolumn{…}` command which makes latex think there's only one row. If at the beginning of the last line, you add an empty cell via `\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}` as a workaround, you'll get a full vertical line. Btw, I've just added a small correction to `\multirow{cell}` for a better centring of the rotated text.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily draw such table with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`. In that environment, you use `\Block` to merge cells (both horizontally and vertically) and you use `hvlines` to draw all the rules excepted in the blocks and in the corners (specified by the key `corners`).

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\begin{NiceTabular}{ccccccc}[hvlines,corners=NW] % NW = north west
& & \Block{1-5}{something} \\ 
& & AAA & BBB & CCC & DDD & EEE\\ 
\Block{2-1}<\rotate>{sth}
& line 1 & x & x & x & x & x \\ 
& line 2 & x & x & x & x & x \\ 
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

**You need several compilations** (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz).

[image: Output of the above code]